# PHP: Check if the value exists in csv file

Tags: php

I've a list of clients in csv file as:

```
Name,Credited
ABC,Y
BCD,Y
XYZ
ABC
```

My task is to check, if the client already exists in the list:

- IF yes, check if he is already credited.
- If yes, delete that name from the list.

I've started writing the code, but not sure how can I achieve my task.

```
//Store the file in array
 $fcsv = file($files); 
 foreach($headers as $header) {
    // Push headers to new array.
    array_push($headings, strtolower(trim($header)));
  }
```

Can someone please help!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This variable **$headers**.. where do you initialize it and with what?

Comment: Hi Ed: Headers is initialised as $headers = explode(",", $fcsv[0]);

Comment: To start with, why don't you use PHP's built-in [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function?

Comment: @MarkBaker. Happy to use fgetcsv.. but I am not still not sure how can I play with Arrays and achieve my desired output.  Sorry I am new to PHP, and still learning..

Comment: Do you really have a variable number of spaces between the two columns in the file?

Comment: No my csv file looks like this username,credited
ABC,Y
BCD,Y
XYZ,
ABC,

Comment: Please edit the question and show what the file really looks like. How do you expect us to give a correct answer if you show the wrong data?

Comment: Sorry @Barmar. I've updated the question. There is "," in the csv file, not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic implementation of searching if the name of the client exist in the given csv file.

```
$client = "ABC";
$fcsv   = file('uploads/task.csv');

foreach ($fcsv as $key => $value) {
  $temp = explode(',', $value);
  if ($temp[0] == $client) {
    unset($fcsv[$key]);
  }
}
```

Each rows in `csv`, if you look at it using var_dump() would look like this,

```
"Name,Credited"
```

If your csv file contains of more than one rows, this line

```
$fcsv = file('uploads/task.csv');
```

will return array of rows, using a `loop` split the content of each rows using `explode(',', $value);`for you to have a data in every column of the rows.

Like in the example above you can now chose, which column you need look, to be able for you to compare where the client exist and delete.

Comment: There are no commas in his file, why are you using comma in `explode`?

Comment: Why are you testing `if ($temp[1] == $client)`? In his file, the client name is just the first column, the second column is `Y` if the client is credited.

Comment: Agree @Barmar. The client name is always the first column and Credited is the second column.

Comment: In any given csv file, compose of many culumn, if you try to browse using php, column are separated with comma,

Comment: Read the question, he showed the file format at the beginning. It uses spaces to separate the client name from the `Y` for credited.

Comment: I think its just an example of the csv content.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Fil. I can't initialise $client = "name_of_client", as the code should browse through and check for all clients (usernames)..  Also, my list contains only 2 columns ..

Comment: @Ravi You can replace `$client` according to the ways you can provide value you can use to compare with `$fcsv` and I updated my last answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the lines in the file, and use `str_getcsv()` to parse it as a CSV line. Then check if the first column is the client name and the second is `Y`.

```
$clients = file($files, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$deleted = false;
foreach ($clients as $index => $client_line) {
    $split = str_getcsv($client_line);
    if ($split[0] == $client) {
        if (isset($split[1]) && $split[1] == 'Y') {
            unset($clients[$index]);
            $deleted = true;
        }
        break; // Stop searching after we found the client
    }
}
// Rewrite the file if we deleted the client.
if ($deleted) {
    file_put_contents($files, implode("\n", $clients));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @barmar. I've update the question. There is "," (comma) in the file, not white spaces.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `str_getcsv` instead of a regular expression.